# Unable to authorize Google App Scripts in order to create a new contact

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been working for Google Apps Script for a while.  I have many programs where I've authorized Gmail, Docs, Drive, Calendar, UI, etc...  I'm just now adding Contacts...but it is not working

My first step is to Contacts.createContact(), but this is failing no matter what I've done.  Documentation says that the "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds" scope is needed.  I have that.  I also added "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts"

I've turned on API in the Admin for the Workspace.  I've made the app the trusted.  I've removed authorization for everything and readded.  The odd thing is that in giving authorization when it lists everything asking for permissions, under contacts is says "Contacts: See, edit, delete..."  It specifically does not say "Create".

I've followed all of the documentation I can find for Google and turned on everything and given permissions to everything.  Still, I cannot createContact.

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: This is not a problem with the code.  It was authorization.  I gave an answer.  The explanation was to not have people focus on code that was correct but on the authorization for the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't post code, because it was not a code problem.  After hours and hours of trial and error, I found the problem.  This is not documented anywhere that I could find in Google.  Google support couldn't figure it out as well. I've left feedback that they will hopefully take.

I hope this helps someone else who is running into this problem.  It was caused by the fact that the very first method I was trying executing in order to bring up the authorization was the ContactsApp.createContact().  Calling this first and in order to bring authorization appears to not be allowed or something they will permit as the very first operation.  Don't know if this is security related.

I changed my code instead to use ContactsApp.getContact() to a known and existing contact.  That code worked!!!  Authorization popped up. Granted. Got the info. I then changed the code back to the .createContact()....it all worked fine.

This appears to only be when you are first trying to use the ContactApp and authorize it for the very first time in your code.  Perhaps it was just a glitch in my account, but the same glitch could happen for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
function createADoggieContact() {
  ContactsApp.createContact("Cooper","Dachshund","Cooper@cooper.com");
}
```

[createContact](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contacts-app#createContact(String,String,String))

Comment: That is the same as my code and does work now.  If you put that as the first ever executed code in a new project and try to get authorization to popup and confirm, I would be interested to know if you get the same error I did?  It appears that Google will throw an error instead of bringing the initial authorization popup if that is the very first code executed for ContactsApp.  Once I tried getContact() as my first code, the authorization popup worked, granted and then createContact would function.

Comment: @GregGriffin I just executed this as the first ever executed code in a new project and everything worked, no errors.

Comment: Like I said, Google tech support couldn't figure it out either.  It could be a unique problem, but if it happened for me, it could happen to others.  The code for this answer is already what I had and was not the answer to my problem and my question.  The answer was to run ContactsApp.getContact() first, and then everything worked.  Doing this code for this answer was the problem, not the answer.